# How can you tell when the RIP tide in Avarice is over?

Tags: x4-foundations

I'm at a station in Avarice I and got the "come to Tidebreak" tide warning while docked. It's been a while (I can't see how long because that warning doesn't get logged in alerts) and nothing seems to have happened.

[image]

How can I tell when the tide happens/ends?